# Validate the merge keys error when using trying to merge two csv columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am incredibly new to coding.
I am trying to merge two .csv files on the column 'FIPS' which holds a four or five digit number (Example  1001 or 54780) and keep getting a lengthy error I can't make sense of?

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\RSHAR\Documents\Research Project\MortAC2006\MULT2006.USPSAllCnty\MULT2006.USAllCnty.csv", header=None, usecols=[0], names=['col']).drop_duplicates()
b = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\RSHAR\Documents\Research Project\MortAC2006\MULT2006.USPSAllCnty\EQI MATCH.csv", header=None, usecols=[0], names=['col']).drop_duplicates()
# A - B
pd.merge(A, B, on='FIPS', how='left', indicator=True).query("_merge == 'left_only'")
```

Here is my error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-e1fef2814734> in <module>
      4 b = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\RSHAR\Documents\Research Project\MortAC2006\MULT2006.USPSAllCnty\EQI MATCH.csv", header=None, usecols=[0], names=['col']).drop_duplicates()
      5 # A - B
----> 6 pd.merge(A, B, on='FIPS', how='left', indicator=True).query("_merge == 'left_only'")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     84         copy=copy,
     85         indicator=indicator,
---> 86         validate=validate,
     87     )
     88     return op.get_result()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    625             self.right_join_keys,
    626             self.join_names,
--> 627         ) = self._get_merge_keys()
    628 
    629         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_merge_keys(self)
    981                     if not is_rkey(rk):
    982                         if rk is not None:
--> 983                             right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
    984                         else:
    985                             # work-around for merge_asof(right_index=True)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1690             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1691         else:
-> 1692             raise KeyError(key)
   1693 
   1694         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'FIPS'
```

Comment: `FIPS` is not in the column list. maybe`on='col'`?

Answer (score 2):

One or both of your dataframes do not have a column FIPS. Before you merge:

```
print(a.columns)
print(b.columns)
```

will show 'col' as your column name in both dataframes because of:

```
names=['col']
```